# Why does the order of assigning ids to words matter when using an embedding?

Tags: tensorflow

In the [data preparation code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/reader.py#L37)
 of tensorflows LSTM example the vocabulary is sorted such that words with higher frequency are assigned a lower id. I know that there are cases where such an order is important. However, in the LSTM code I can not see where the order of assigning ids to words would matter. **Still it does** as omitting the sort gives different results **even if one uses a constant initializer for initializing the embedding.** Why is that?

Comment: Hey @ben, did you get an answer to this? I would love to know the reason

Comment: @martianwars Unfortunately not yet.